# Restore VS Code settings in new machine

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for some months and have made a lot of tweaks and settings on it (plugins, themes, shortcuts etc).

Now i'm moving to a new machine. Is there a quick way to backup / restore my current settings on the new machine when i install VS code on it ?

Thanks

Comment: You can find all of the configuration information on Windows in `%USERPROFILE5\AppData\Roaming\Code`.

Comment: See the Settings Sync extension as well https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link: https://github.com/kayawebd/VScode-Backup-and-restore-on-new-PC

This batch file simplifies the process of transferring VSCode to another computer. Follow these steps:

Download and extract the zip files.

Run Copy_Old_VSCode_Data_To_This_Folder.bat.

Copy the entire VSCode_Backup folder to the new PC.

On the new PC, run Run_This_On_New_PC_To_Copy_Data_From_This_Folder_To_New_VSCode.bat.

Your setup is now complete! Test VSCode to ensure everything is working as expected.